# Stuck with kde at login screen?

Tags: xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu, I was happy with xfce4 interface but then I decided to try out the other ones, so I installed kde and gnome just so I get to know which one is best for me.

Problem is, now when I start my computer, the login screen is using KDE screen. 
I can still choose xfce interface when logging a user, but at the login screen I'm stuck with KDE, how do I change that without having to unistall kde?

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and select which login screen you want `lightdm` or `gdm` etc..